# NA cost function for tensorflow

Tags: python, dataframe, tensorflow, int

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy

#download csv data sheet of all cell lines
input_data = pd.read_csv(
    'C:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxx/xxx.csv',
    index_col=[0, 1],
    header=0,
    na_values='---')
matrix_data = input_data.as_matrix()

#user define cell lines of interest for supervised training
group1 = input("Please enter cell lines that makes up the your cluster of interest with spaces in between(case sensitive):")
group_split1 = group1.split(sep=" ")

#assign label of each: input cluster = 1
#                      rest of cluster = 0
#extract data of input group
g1 = input_data.loc[:,group_split1]
g2 = input_data.loc[:,[x for x in list(input_data) if x not in group_split1]]
regroup = pd.concat([g1,g2], axis=1, join_axes=[g1.index])
regroup = numpy.transpose(regroup.as_matrix())

labels = numpy.zeros(shape=[len(regroup),1])
labels[0:len(group_split1)] = 1

#define variables
trainingtimes = 1000

#create model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 54781])
w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([54781,1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
#define linear regression model, loss function
y = tf.nn.sigmoid((tf.matmul(x,w)+b))

#define correct training group
ytt = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

#define cross optimizer and cost function
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y, ytt))

#train step
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(mse)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

for i in range(trainingtimes):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: regroup, ytt:labels})
    if i%100 == 0:
        print(sess.run(mse, feed_dict={x:regroup, ytt:labels}))
```

My input x and y data: x is a 141*54871 matrix with each row representing a cell and each 54871 column as a gene expression level of a gene of the cell (of that row). y is a 141*1 one column label that distinguishes group1 from group2 by labeling a cell either as 0 or 1 for group 1 or 2.

my cost function mse only prints nan. Is there something wrong with having too many neurons? or What would be the issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your placeholder `x` is overridden by the integer `x` in the for loop. So the variable `x` in `feed_dict` is the one comes from `range(trainingtimes)`, which is definitely not a TF tensor.

Rename the variable `x` to avoid the problem:

```
for i in range(trainingtimes):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: regroup, ytt:labels})
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print(sess.run(mse, feed_dict={x:regroup, ytt:labels}))
```

Comment: Wow. Dumb mistake. Thank you. However, now I run it the mse function only prints nan. Is there something wrong with having too many neurons (in this case 54871)? Thank you!

Comment: I don't see the same behavior using random inputs. Does `regroup` contain any NaN?

Comment: Also, since it's a different problem, you should probably post a new question instead of reusing this one. This answer is off-topic now, given the new question and title.

Comment: I see. I renamed the topic and everything is this fine or shoud I reopen a question. And no there are no Nan in them. They are just a bunch of numbers in a matrix